# Problem with sending object via wcf service with private fields

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I have a class `Car`

```
public class Car
{
    private Member _owner;

    public string OwnerName
    {
        get { return _owner.Name; }
    }

    public Car(Member owner)
    {
        _owner = owner;
    }
}
```

I'm using it both at Silverlight application and wcf service

So, at application I call WCF service to give me instance of car class, but when I get it at application, I see that `_owner` is empy.

I know that it is empty because of private, but how can I deal with it?

I'm using this class in my app as model (MVVM) if it could helps :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start none of your properties are marked as DataMembers.  The class isn't marked as a DataContract.  If this is getting returned from a WCF service I would expect to see:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Car
{
      private Member _owner;
      [DataMember]
      public string OwnerName
      {
          //getter
          //setter
       }

      etc..
}
```

Does Member have to be private?  Could it be converted into a property?

Keep in mind that a [DataMember] property needs both a set and a get (so that WCF can read into and from the object).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From a WCF serialization point of view, your Car class actually looks something like this to the WCF service:

```
public class Car
{
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    //other public properties here....
}
```

The WCF serializer uses the .NET class definition as a template for serializing its contents as a simple data transfer object. When the WCF service sends back a Car instance, only the public properties will contain values. The serializer ignores all methods in the class. Also, later versions of WCF don't require the DataContract/DataMember attribute markup.

The _owner variable is never initialized because it is not part of the public properties of the Car class. You'll need to modify the structure of the Car class (maybe add a public Owner property of type Member) to get all the data sent from the WCF service to your client.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the default Data Contract Serializer with WCF services it serializes and deserializes only the public properties of the class. Also another thing to note is that while deserializing the object graph the constructor is not called. You can have a public property with getter  and setter.

[Here](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/default.aspx) is a very nice article by Jeremy Likeness explaining the problem similar to yours. From Architecture as well as best practices point of view you can use a POCO class generally called as DTO (Data Transfer Object) when transferring objects between the service layer and the clients.